# Raku: How do I assign values to CArray[WCHAR]?

Tags: raku, nativecall

$ raku -v
    This is Rakudo version 2019.07.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.07.1

The following was done on Raku REPL.   What am I doing wrong here?  How do I assign values to CArray[WCHAR]?

I want $lpData[0] to be 0xABCD   and   $lpData[1] to be 0xEF12.

```
> use NativeCall;
Nil

> constant WCHAR := uint16;
(uint16)

> my $ValueData = 0xABCDEF12;
2882400018

> my CArray[WCHAR]  $lpData;
(CArray[uint16])

> $lpData[ 0 ] =  ( $ValueData +& 0xFFFF0000 ) +> 0x10;
Type check failed in assignment to $lpData; expected NativeCall::Types::CArray[uint16] but got Array ($[])
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

> $lpData[ 1 ] =    $ValueData +& 0x0000FFFF;
Type check failed in assignment to $lpData; expected NativeCall::Types::CArray[uint16] but got Array ($[])
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Many thanks,
-T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is stated clearly in the error message: in the way you declare it, it's expecting every item to be a CArray[WCHAR]. Declare it this way, as is indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#index-entry-CArray):

```
use NativeCall;
constant WCHAR = uint16; # No need to bind here also
my $native-array = CArray[WCHAR].new(); 
$native-array[0] = 0xABCDEF12 +& 0x0000FFFF;
say $native-array.list; # OUTPUT: «(-4334)␤»
```

`CArray` is not exactly a `Positional`, but it does have `AT-POS` defined so you can use square brackets to assign values. The error arises when, you try to assign to an non-initialized `Scalar` (which contains any) as if it were an array. The minimal change from your program is just initializing to a CArray[WCHAR]:

```
use NativeCall;
constant WCHAR = uint16; # No need to bind here also
my CArray[WCHAR] $native-array .= new; 
$native-array[0] = 0xABCDEF12 +& 0x0000FFFF;
say $native-array.list; # OUTPUT: «(-4334)␤»
```

Comment: @Todd please remember to vote up and/or accept one answer as correct (in this and in the other questions)

Comment: There is a certain waiting period if I answer my own question.

Comment: On Windows, Mac and Linux, this outputs `(61202)`, not `(-4334)`.